# Configure CoordinatorLayout from code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm dynamically injecting a content view into the `CoordinatorLayout` and would now like to apply a `layout_below` property to the injected view so that it isn't hidden behind the `AppBar`.

Is there any way to do this at runtime from code instead of xml properties of the annotation?

Comment: Unlike `RelativeLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout`, which is similar to `FrameLayout`, does not have `layout_below` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking one step back and building the entire view in plain xml, I realized that `layout_below` is not the property I needed for my use case: placing the content view below the app bar. I did not make this clear in my question though, as I assumed `layout_below` would be the proper option for that.

In fact, to insert a non scrolling view into the `CoordinatorLayout` it should first be wrapped with a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`. Then, to avoid its content being hidden behind the app bar, it is necessary to update its behavior to `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`. Otherwise a default behavior is used which will hide behind the app bar.

```
val viewToInsert = getLayoutInflater.inflate( id, coordinatorWrapper, false )
val p = viewToInsert.getLayoutParams.asInstanceOf[Coordinator.LayoutParams]
p.setBehavior( new ScrollingViewBehavior )
coordinatorWrapper.addView( viewToInsert, 1, p )
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting an `anchor`.

```
ContentView view = getContentView(); //your view
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

params.setAnchorId(R.id.app_bar_layout);
params.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM; //we will anchor to the bottom line of the appbar
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM; //we want to be BELOW that line
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I tried this as well; it seems very straight forward. But it appears to have no effect. Is this working for you?

Comment: I never tried, but it should. Try refreshing the layout somehow (i.e., `coordinator.requestLayout()`, `coordinator.recomputeViewAttributes(view)`,... don't know which you should use exactly. Edited my answer with a new line also.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly valid an correct, however `layout_below` was not the option I needed (which you could not know from my question). I added a detailed answer describing how to solve the problem.